# How To allow POST and GET request only for current users's data?

Tags: django, authentication, django-views, django-queryset

I want to show only their data for each user. So one user cannot GET or POST another user's data.

```
class FcaSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self): 
        return Fca.objects.filter(user_check= request.user) #user filter
    serializer_class = FcaSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
```

But usually it throws error: TypeError at /api/cutarea-fca/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'

Next I try use this:

```
def get_queryset(self): 
        return Fca.objects.filter(user_check= request.user)
```

but user doesn't see no one object from this model in frontend...

It is model:

```
class Fca(models.Model):
    num_of_agree = models.ForeignKey(Agreement, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    uroch = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_allot = models.ForeignKey(Allotment, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    num_fca = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    ar_fca = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    expl_ar = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    cel_nazn = models.ForeignKey(ForestPurpose, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='task',blank=True, null=True) 
    cat_zas = models.ForeignKey(ForestProtection, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='cate',blank=True, null=True ) 
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(geography=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ge')
    video_cat = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_check = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='user_id',blank=True, null=True )




    class Meta:
        managed = True
        verbose_name = 'lek'
        verbose_name_plural =  'leks'
```

There is serializer:

```
class FcaSerializer(gis_serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Fca
        geo_field = 'geom'
        fields = ('id','num_of_agree','num_allot','uroch','num_fca','ar_fca',\
       'expl_ar','cel_nazn','cat_zas','geom','video_cat','user_check')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Fca.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

I hope somebody text how to solve this classic task by simple example or psedo code

Comment: That's telling you that you don't have a logged-in user. You should probably use the LoginRequiredMixin, or since this is DRF you can set `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)`.

Comment: Thank you!  I have learnt it. But I have one more question: Could you now how to do trick like this, but filter will token of User after login event instead User id filter.